# estimating parameters using optim in R, table tennis dataset

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset containing two binary variables of a table tennis game: service.A shows whether a player is on service or not and point.A shows whether player A scored the point or not.

Each point is weighted by an importance factor. A factor between 1 and 3 showing the importance of that particular point.

I want to estimate the four parameters strengthP1Service, strengthP1Return..  These are estimations of a player while serving or returning.

The code gives no errors, however I’m not getting an output from the optim function with an estimation (the MLE) for the four parameters. 
If anyone could help me getting estimations for the four parameters, I’d would be very grateful.

Many thanks,
Wim

```
myfunction <- function(data, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, importance) {
  N <- length(data)
  nllfunction<-function(p){
    strengthP1Service<- p[1]
    strengthP1Return<- p[2]
    strengthP2Service<- p[3]
    strengthP2Return<- p[4]

# four possible outcomes since there are 2 binary variables
    ratio1 <- strengthP1Service/(strengthP1Service + strengthP2Return) 
    ratio2 <- strengthP2Return/(strengthP1Service + strengthP2Return) 
    ratio3 <- strengthP2Service/(strengthP1Return + strengthP2Service) 
    ratio4 <- strengthP1Return/(strengthP1Return + strengthP2Service) 

# weighted likelihood function
    nll<- -sum(log(ratio1^((data$service.A==1 & data$point.A == 1)*importance) *
                     ratio2^((data$service.A==1 & data$point.A == 0)*importance) *
                     ratio3^((data$service.A==0 & data$point.A == 0)*importance) *
                     ratio4^((data$service.A==0 & data$point.A == 1)*importance)))

    return(nll)
  }
    out<-optim(par=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),  
             fn=myfunction, gr=NULL, method="L-BFGS-B",
             lower=c(0,0,0,0), upper=c(1,1,1,1))
  }



# first lines of the dataset
Player.A Player.B service.A punt.A importance
1   Sharon  Kenneth         1      1        2.0
2   Sharon  Kenneth         1      1        2.0
3   Sharon  Kenneth         0      1        2.0
4   Sharon  Kenneth         0      1        2.0
5   Sharon  Kenneth         1      0        1.5
6   Sharon  Kenneth         1      1        2.0
```

Comment: can you share sample data

Comment: I included some lines of the dataset in the description of my question.

Comment: do you really want to learn 4 params? since ratio1 + ratio2 = ratio3 + ratio4 = 1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I want 4 parameters. If I had only 2 players in my dataset, 2 parameters would be sufficient indeed. But I have a dataset containing 45 matches from a round-robin tournament of 9 players. I could continue to do the analysis if the optim function gives me an output. But since I get no error, I do not know what I'm doing wrong